# How to get contact picture on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How to get a contact picture or contact image on Windows phone 7 on user selection using phoneNumber picker.

```
        PhoneNumberChooserTask phoneNumberChooserTask;
        phoneNumberChooserTask = new PhoneNumberChooserTask();
        phoneNumberChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhoneNumberResult>(phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed);
        phoneNumberChooserTask.Show();
```

and my method after the user has picked the contact

```
public void phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhoneNumberResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The phone number for " + e.DisplayName + " is " + e.PhoneNumber);                
        }
    }
```

the above code is as per the MSDN..
The above code shows the phone number. 
**How to get the contact image location or data URI?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's quite simple:

Add reference `using Microsoft.Phone.UserData`. Then when your Task is completed, search all contacts by name or phone number for example:

```
    private void phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhoneNumberResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
            contacts.SearchCompleted += OnContactsSearchCompleted;
            contacts.SearchAsync(e.PhoneNumber, FilterKind.PhoneNumber, null);
        }
    }

    private void OnContactsSearchCompleted(object sender, ContactsSearchEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Results != null)
        {
            var contactImg = e.Results.Select(x => x.GetPicture()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (contactImg != null)
            {
                //do something with
            }
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to add Capability **ID_CAP_CONTACTS**

Comment: The above code works for raw image data..how to get contact pic file path and not the image buffer..

Answer (score 0):

Because contact photos are not properties, but instead are retrieved by calling the GetPicture method, you need a custom data converter to bind them. In this procedure, you put the code in a button click event for testing purposes only. In your own applications, you can access contact photos wherever you need them. 
For more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286418(v=vs.105).aspx